# SPSS Modeler setting the parametr in python script

Tags: python, ibm-watson, spss-modeler

I have a one problem with SPSS. I want to set the parameter using the python script.
The parametr name is pMacroregion and I'm using this parameter in Select Node. In this node I set the column value is equal the parametr value.

In my script, I entry parametr value, but when I add output table, i receive nothing.

```
import modeler.api

stream = modeler.script.stream()

selectnode = stream.findByID("idTDVEN4CV5I") # select node
tablenode = stream.findByID("idT4WQLYPH6Z") # Table output node
selectnode.setPropertyValue("mode", "Include")
pMacroregion = "CENTRAL EUROPE"
stream.setParameterValue("pMacroregion", pMacroregion)
selectnode.setPropertyValue("condition", "'Macroregion' = '$pMacroregion'")


tablenode.run([])
```

Can you tell me, what is wrong ?

Comment: I find the solution. The error was in penultimate line.  I change the parametr value from
'$pMacroregion' to  '$P-pMacroregion'.

`selectnode.setPropertyValue("condition", "'Macroregion' = '$P-pMacroregion'")`
`tablenode.run([])`